Thévenin's theorem exercise with two voltage sources
I have the following exercise:
I need to use thevenin's theorem to get the equivalent voltage source and resistor

I have redrawn it in LTSpice for better understanding:

I knew how to get the equivalent resistance : (R1*R2)/(R1+R2)
But how to get the equivalent voltage source?
When i use the superposition theorem it's V = V1 + V2 * R2/(R1+R2) but that is wrong.
How can i solve this ? And what have i done wrong using the superposition theorem ?
Reference for the picture : https://stefan-schenke.de/get/challenges/Training_Ersatzquellen.pdf

Please provide a reference for the image, as required by the rules here.  Does the asymmetry in your result suggest anything? Also you do need to indicate a reference node or your sign might be wrong.

Are those current sources or voltage sources?

Both are voltage sources

You short out one supply at a time, which I guess you have. Then you need to be aware of where the voltage is measured. How do you come to the conclusion that it is V1 + something?

@TimGraf - Hi, I have removed the new question from your self-answer. Although there are a couple of different approaches you could use if you want to ask a new, related question, the easiest (and least confusing for future readers) is to post a new self-contained question containing what you now want to ask, with a link to this one for context, if relevant. || The thing to avoid is changing the question, or asking a new one, inside an "answer" since then it isn't an answer any more. TY

As a tip, you can switch the positions of R1 and V1 without changing any of the circuit behavior (aside from the voltage at the intermediate node between R1 and V1). That might make it easier to see how to calculate the open-circuit output voltage wihtout resorting to superposition.

@SamGibson Thank you for the hint.

Thanks to Tyassin I now know what I have done wrong in the superposition theorem. It's V = V1 * R2/(R1+R2) + V2 * R1/(R1+R2) = (V1*R2+V2*R1) / (R1+R2).
To calculate with mesh currents, get the total current which is (V1-V2)/(R1+R2) then get the voltage drop on R2 which is I * R2 and then add those two up to get the voltage on OUT. So the voltage on out is : (V1-V2)/(R1+R2) * R2 + V2
